# How can I make it run on all my domains powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a script that runs only on my domain but I want it to run on every domain, because it find users in my domain but not other domains

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$Username
)

$user = Get-ADUser -Identity $Username

if ($user) {
    $managedGroups = Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter "(managedBy=$($user.DistinguishedName))" |
                     Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

    if ($managedGroups) {
        Write-Host "Groups managed by user '$Username':"
        $managedGroups | Sort-Object | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ }
    } else {
        Write-Host "User '$Username' does not manage any groups."
    }
} else {
    Write-Host "User '$Username' not found."
}
```

I tried to get every group that is managed by a Username

Comment: if you want to query a user in a different domain then you can use the `-Server` parameter. same applies for if you want to query for groups managed by the user

Answer (score 0):

When used in the way you are above, Get-ADUser / Get-ADGroup and the other related cmdlets all operate by default just in the current AD domain.

In order to query another domain you need to include the `-server` parameter to explicitly tell the command to connect to and query a different AD server for your request. Note, with non-AD related cmdlets (for instance MS Exchange) you'll find the same thing can be done, but the option will tend to be `-domaincontroller` instead, but it works the same way.

So you'd need to query each AD domain individually and get your results from each of them. I'm not aware of a way to query all the domains in an entire forest with a single query (I've looked in the past).

All of this obviously assumes that you have the required domain trusts and permissions in place, such that you can query one domain from within another of course. If not then you may also need to specify the `-credential` parameter and provide the needed credentuals to allow the query.

Note, the `-server` and `-domaincontroller` parameters both require a named server, eg `server1.dom1.mydomain.com`, and don't allow you to simply specify the domain `dom1.mydomain.com` as a whole. So I've ended up using this

```
$dcDom1 = get-addomaincontroller -discover -domain dom1.mydomain.com -forcediscover | Select-Object -expandproperty hostname
```

which finds one available DC within the "dom1.mydomain.com" AD domain, selects the hostname and then assigns it to $dcDom1. That way it doesn't matter if the specific DCs within the domain change, or aren't online at a particular point in time.